# What type of project would I use for a C# program that runs in the background with no UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio, scheduled-tasks

I'm used to making win forms or web-based apps that kick off the code through a user interface.  I need to create a program that runs at regular intervals without any user input.  What type of Visual Studio project would I use to create this?  How do I start the program without a UI?

Here's what the program would need to do:

- Be written in C#, asp.net with a SQL database
- Require no user input
- Run at a regular interval (i.e. everyday at 1 p.m.)
- Run stored procedures on a SQL query
- Take the results of the SQL query and output to a text file
- Encrypt the text file
- Zip several text files together
- Send the zip file to a URL

I thought of creating a win form and then having a Windows scheduled task call it, but I'm not sure how to create an application that can be called by a Windows scheduled task.  I'm also worried about having a Windows task because the user's computer would have to be on.  I'd rather use a SQL job (I'm more familiar with them), but am unsure how to do the encryption and file management from SQL and don't know how to create an application that can be called by SQL (I usually have a web application that retrieves data from SQL).

As you can tell, this is new to me, so any suggestions (especially samples and links to resources) would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Why creating a Windows Form for an application with no GUI? Create either a console application or Windows Service. " I'm also worried about having a Windows task because the user's computer would have to be on" - no, there is an option to run the task regardless of someone being logged in or not...

Comment: I would create a service. It gets started when the computer is started regardless when someone has logged in or not

Comment: If you have access to SQL Server, a common pattern is to use the SQL Job Agent to run an SSIS package that orchestrates these tasks. Otherwise the best method is probably a windows service.

Comment: A Windows Service.... this way it will run even if no one is logged on tot he machine.  It can be started automatically when the machine boots, or manually from the Service Control Manager (SCM), runs under a designated service account, and can be programmed to kick off another chunk of code (say in a referenced dll) at whatever scheduled dates/times you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to disagree with the Windows Service answer. While that would definitely work too, personally I'd use a scheduled task:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx

I haven't tested this personally, here's an article on how to run the scheduled task without the command window showing:
http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/

The suggestion in the comments to use SQL Server's scheduled job sounds reasonable to me too.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  What would my C# project look like?   Maybe a win form that didn't have any ui to it?  How would I start such a program?  (Usually it would start with index.html, for example, but without html or other ui, what's "the beginning" of the program?)

Comment: Probably a console application. There are ways to run the console application without actually showing the console window (which is obviously highly desirable from a user perspective). You then make your executable a Scheduled Task and Windows will automatically start it for you at the time you specified. (The only caveat - I haven't written one in a little while but last I checked there's a limit to how much precision they'll actually guarantee you as to the *exact* start time, check the documentation for exactly how much they'll guarantee).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for a Windows Service.

- In Visual Studio click on File -> New -> Project.
- Select "Windows Desktop" template -> and click on Windows Service.

Once the service is created you can instantiate a `System.Timers.Timer` object and create an event that would run at a specific interval:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My.New.Service
{
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        public MyService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            double interval = Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WindowsServiceTimer"].ToString());

            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval); //Runs timer every X milliseconds
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This look like a good timer, but where would I call the main project to start the file processing I need to do?  Typically the program would start at index.html, for example, but how do I start a program without a beginning like that?

Comment: When you install the WIndows Service it will automatically run the OnStart() method which will register a timer and the timer will run every X amount of milliseconds.The service will run the whole time unless the server is re-started or the service sis manually stopped.Have a look here on step by step guide on how to create a Windows Service - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx